# Use of Divi Builder with WpBakery not working

Tags: wordpress

I have installed workscout theme which has wp-bakery builder for page building, I have installed divi-builder and created pages with it. It was working correctly before but now divi builder pages are not displaying correctly but in page builder view it shows correctly.

[Here is the page that is not displaying:](https://whitecoatstaffing.com/white-coat-advisory-board/)

Here are details of error in console log:

```
divi-builder.min.js?ver=4.0.9:97 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
at divi-builder.min.js?ver=4.0.9:97
at divi-builder.min.js?ver=4.0.9:97
at divi-builder.min.js?ver=4.0.9:97
at divi-builder.min.js?ver=4.0.9:97
```